# Creating a view

Tags: android

hi please help 
actually i m trying to make list view as invisible 
but its showing the listview and gridview both at one time please help in solving it.
here is the code.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) { 
        super.onCreate(icicle); 
        setContentView(R.layout.main); 
        Gallery gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery1);
     lst=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
     lst.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
   //  ViewManager hi=(ViewManager)getBaseContext().getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE );


        gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));        
        final GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);

        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        data = new Vector<RowData>();
        for(int i=0;i<title.length;i++){
        try {
            rd = new RowData(i,title[i],detail[i]);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
           }
           data.add(rd);
           lst.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.list,R.id.title,data));
        }

        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAd(this));

        final TabHost tabs=(TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabhost); 


        tabs.setup(); 

        final TabHost.TabSpec spec=tabs.newTabSpec("buttontab"); 
        final TabHost.TabSpec spec1=tabs.newTabSpec("btn"); 
        spec.setContent(R.id.list);
        lst.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        spec1.setContent(R.id.buttontab);
        spec.setIndicator("tab1");

        spec1.setIndicator("tab1");
        tabs.addTab(spec); 
        tabs.setCurrentTab(0); 
        tabs.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setLayoutParams(new
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams(30,30));
spec.setIndicator("tab2");
        tabs.addTab(spec);
        tabs.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setLayoutParams(new
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams(30,30));
        tabs.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
                if(tabId=="buttontab")
```

and here is xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50px"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:layout_width="80px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Login"
    />
    <TextView
    android:paddingLeft="80px"
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:layout_width="40px"
    android:text="Search"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    />
    <EditText

    android:layout_width="100px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
    </LinearLayout>
     <Gallery
        android:id="@+id/gallery1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="50px" /> 

   <TabHost android:id="@+id/tabhost" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 
        <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        /> 
        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:paddingTop="62px"> 
            <ListView android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="200px" />   
            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >


         <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="200px"
    android:numColumns="4"
    android:verticalSpacing="5px"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5px"
    android:columnWidth="60dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
/>    
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
<Button
android:id="@+id/buttontab"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/icon"/>
<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/hello1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/icon"/>

<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/hello3"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/icon"/>
<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/hello4"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/icon"/>
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/hello5"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/icon"/>

</LinearLayout>
          </LinearLayout>>
        </FrameLayout> 
    </TabHost>  
</LinearLayout>
```

so please help to make listview as invisiblei know its a very little mistake but unable to solve the error

Answer (score 0):

Try View.GONE instead of View.INVISIBLE

Since you are doing this in onCreate you could do it in your XML:

```
 <ListView 
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="200px" 
    android:visibility="gone"
 />
```